# (Angular) For a non-empty path with no matching route, why does the browser's address bar revert to root url?

Tags: angular, routes

I have created a brand new Angular application using:
ng new testApp --no-standalone --ssr=false --no-strict

I have not make any changes to the application. The default app-routing.module.ts looks like:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Suppose I host my application at http://localhost:51713/.

PROBLEM:
When I put http://localhost:51713/xyz to the browser's address bar and hit enter, why does the browser's address bar revert back to the root url http://localhost:51713/ ?? Given there is no matching route and no default catch all route set up, shouldn't browser's address bar remains at http://localhost:51713/xyz ?

Thanks.

I don't understand this behaviour, as I would have thought the browser's address bar would stay at http://localhost:51713/xyz.

I have tested this in:

- multiple different browsers (Chrome, Edge, Firefox)
- node.js development server, firebase production server

Answer (score 0):

Because there are no routes on your `app-routing.module.ts`.

What if you add this:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'xyz', component: XyzComponent },
];
```